# Java generics incompatible types (no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist)

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

The question title may seem to be same as some other post but the content is different. So please don't mark it duplicate.

**Problem**:

I have the below class:

```
public class SCDTO extends RDTO {
    private List<String> sCPairs = Collections.emptyList();

    public SCDTO(List<String> sCPairs) {
        this.sCPairs = sCPairs;
    }

    //Getter setter
    
}
```

I am trying to using the below lambda expression to set the `sCPairs`.

```
sCPairsObject.setSCPairs(
         util.getSCMap().entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains("abc"))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<String>::new))
);
```

But I have an compilation error saying:

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Entry<String, List<String>> conforms to String
```

`util.getSCMap` returns `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening and how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: `entrySet()` will return a `Set<Entry<K,V>>` so if you want to collect those into a `List<String>` you'll need a `map(...)` in between - or if `V` is actually a `List<String>` you might even need a `flatMap(...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are streaming entries from the map:

```
sCPairsObject.setSCPairs(util.getSCMap().entrySet().stream()
```

Then filtering out some of them:

```
.filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains("abc"))
```

now you need to map the entries to List, for example:

```
.map(entry -> entry.getValue())
```

and stream the contents of all these lists as one stream:

```
.flatMap(List::stream)
```

Finally collect the values into a list:

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I cannot mark all the reply as Answer otherwise I marked this as answer also.

Comment: I think I was the first answer with a complete solution. But IMO Murat's answer is the best currently since it takes into account that you are not using the keys so you don't need to iterate over the entries. The current accepted answer doesn't actually solve your problem since it is not flapmapping the values.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the need of doing .flatMap(List::stream)? What will happen if I don't do it? @Adriaan Koster

Comment: flatmap allows you to collect the contents of a stream of lists into a single stream. If you don't use it then the stream will contain several lists. And then if you do collect(Collectors.toList()) you will end up with a List<List<String>> instead of List<String>

Answer (score 4):

Your stream pipeline finds all the `Map` entries whose value `List<String>` contains the `String` "abc", and tries to collect them into a `List<String>`.

You didn't specify how you intend to convert each `Map.Entry<String,List<String>>` element that passes the filter into a `String`. Depending on the required logic, perhaps you are missing a `map()` step after the filter.

For example, if you wish to collect all the keys having a value that passes the filter into a `List<String>`:

```
 sCPairsObject.setSCPairs(util.getSCMap()
                              .entrySet()
                              .stream()
                              .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains("abc"))
                              .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<String>::new)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over the `entrySet` since you are not using the key at all. You can get the values of the `Map` and filter that. Looks like this

```
sCPairsObject.setSCPairs(util.getSCMap()
   .values()
   .stream()
   .filter(entry -> entry.contains("abc"))
   .flatMap(List::stream)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You could rename the variable 'entry' to e.g. 'value' to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to convert a `Map<String, List<String>>` to a `List<String>` where the list should be a union of all matching value lists you'll need a `flatMap()` to join the streams on those value lists into a single stream.

Additionally you don't seem to need the keys so just stream on the map's values:

```
List<String> scPairs = util.getSCMap().values().stream() //stream on the values only
                           .filter( l -> l.contains( "abc" ) ) //filter the lists
                           .flatMap( Collection::stream ) //join the individual streams
                           .collect( Collectors.toList() ); //collect the result into a single list
```